# Visual Studio Code - pom.xml - Missing Artifacts

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, automation, pom.xml

I am trying to set up automated testing in VScode but am receiving dependency errors from my maven pom.xml files.

I am an automation tester using Gherkin to run test scenarios. I'm still pretty new to it but I need to set up automation in VScode for a new project. Unfortunately, I am having a lot of issues with this. I THINK errors are occuring while trying to download dependencies, but to be honest I really have no idea. I can link to the errors below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
```

```
Failure to transfer org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:pom:0.8.2 from 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, 
resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central 
has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer 
artifact org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:pom:0.8.2 from/to central 
(https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): No such host is known (repo.maven.apache.org)

Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.8.3

Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.23.4

Missing artifact com.{companyName}:cucumber-selenium:jar:5.2.16-SNAPSHOT

Missing artifact org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.8.3

Missing artifact com.{companyName}:oao-app-sdk:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT

Missing artifact org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.23.4

Error while downloading 'http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd' to 
C:\Users\{username}\.lsp4xml\cache\http\maven.apache.org\xsd\maven-4.0.0.xsd.

CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin 
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3 
or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for 
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.3: 
ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact 
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.3 
from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
```

Edit: Updating error logs

Comment: Please do not link errors, but copy them to the question.

Comment: you have to provide your company proxy/repository details in mavens settings.xml (maybe a colleague, who uses maven can help;)

Comment: regarding the stack trace: you can dump large parts of it, and the most significant/confusing/important portion is "Could not transfer
artifact xxx from/to central
(https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): No such host is known"

Comment: you could refer to this:https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/712, may be it could help you